# Django: Filtering Distinct Data

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a messaging app. Here's my model,

```
class Message(models.Model):
sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
msg_content = models.TextField()
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is what I tried in view,

```
data = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user)).order_by('-created_at')
```

In my template,

```
{% for abc in data %}
    {{ abc.receiver }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

How can I print out the distinct users?

Comment: What's your db backend?

Comment: users = User.objects.filter(id__in=data.values_list('receiver_id', flat=True)) ?

Comment: distinct users who has a conversation with the authenticated user ?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Sir, it's Postgresql

Comment: @SachinKukreja Yes sir absolutely. Just like on various social media platforms

Comment: @devxplorer Sir why it's not re-ordering them based on new messages?

Comment: @Randomix oh, sorry, missed this part

Comment: @devxplorer Sir, can you please answer how can I do that? because I tried order_by('-created_at') in data. But it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the senders and receivers separately and then use `set()` to get the distinct values

```
users = set([x.receiver for x in Message.objects.filter(sender = request.user)] + [x.sender for x in Message.objects.filter(receiver = request.user)])
```

Comment: Sir how can I re-order them based upon the `-created_at` ?

Comment: `users = sorted(list(users), key=lambda x: x.created_at, reverse=True)`

Answer (score 0):

With your db structure i was able to receive what your want only with such db query (not sure it can be reproduced in django orm):

```
SELECT u.*, m.*
FROM auth_user u
  INNER JOIN (
     SELECT
       user_id,
       MAX(message_id) AS message_id
     FROM
       (
         SELECT
           m2.receiver_id AS user_id,
           MAX(id)        AS message_id
         FROM yourapp_message m2
         GROUP BY m2.receiver_id
         UNION
         SELECT
           m2.sender_id AS user_id,
           MAX(id)      AS message_id
         FROM yourapp_message m2
         GROUP BY m2.sender_id
       ) t
     GROUP BY user_id) t2 ON u.id = t2.user_id
  INNER JOIN yourapp_message m ON m.id = t2.message_id
ORDER BY m.id DESC
```