# Django: Filtering the Distinct Data

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a messaging app. Here's my model,

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
    msg_content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is what I tried in view,

```
data = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user))
```

In the template,

```
{% for abc in data %}
    {{ abc.receiver }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

How to get distinct users and re-order them based upon new messages as we see on social media platforms?

Comment: 2 message might have same user,  1 for receiver and 1 for sender ? you want filter on sender or receiver  ?

Comment: @Vicmathur Sir I wants to filter the receiver?

Comment: i sorted this by , giving sender , receiver | receiver sender and sort based on time

Comment: try loop through users (Distinct ) and do set_all() for messages , This will give you all messages associated with that user

Comment: do you want to order message or need to get receiver?

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed Sir, I need receiver & re-order receiver as well as messages updates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Filtering Distinct Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47258858/django-filtering-distinct-data)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
inbox_message = Message.objects.filter.objects.filter(receiver=request.user).order_by('-created_at')

outbox_message = Message.objects.filter.objects.filter(sender=request.user).order_by('-created_at')
```

Comment: @Mohideen ibn Mohammed is right please read the question carefully

Comment: Sir, I need receiver & re-order receiver as well as messages updates. Not the messages by them :)

Comment: this is not exactly he want.. it can sort it based on create date.. he want more to do

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed Yes sir this is not what I want. But how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

here thing you need to do,

1. fetch sender `request.user` rec - somename
2. fetch receivedMsg for above sender, receiver `request.user` serder - somename

   message_queue = Message.objects.filter(Q(receiver=rec_name, sender=request.user), Q(receiver=request.user, sender=rec_name).order_by('-created_at')

order by created_at will shuffle like chain