# Django: Distinct Users Filtering

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a messaging app. Here's my model,

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
    msg_content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is what I tried in view,

```
data = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user))
```

In the template,

```
{% for abc in data %}
    {{ abc.receiver }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Here i wants to filter the distinct receivers and re-order them based upon the fact that to whom `request.user` sent new message recently (as we see on social media platforms). How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Filtering the Distinct Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47264754/django-filtering-the-distinct-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write two queries. One is to fetch all the messages and another to get recipient list in order. receiver_list in following code will give you receiver list. Based on receiver list, you can filter out messages in template.

```
from django.db.models.aggregates import Max
data = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user))
receiver_list = data.filter(sender=request.user).values('receiver').annotate(max_time=Max('created_at').order_by('-max_time')
```

Comment: Sir, it's showing the error "SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions". I'm using Postgresql

Comment: Wow! Finally I can take a breath. Thank You very much sir :) It's working fine

Answer (score 0):

Add [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct) in your query

```
data = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user)).values('receiver').distinct().order_by()
```

This query will fetch all the distinct recievers from the message objects

Updated answer:-

.distinct([*fields]) will work with postgresql

```
data = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user)).order_by('receiver','-created_at').distinct('reciever')
```

Comment: Why It's not re-ordering them as user sends a new message?

Comment: It's still ordering the users based upon their `id` not by the fact whom I sent a message most recently

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Postgresql

Comment: Please try the updated answer. Not sure this will work because I didn't try this. let me know if it throws any error

Comment: It's not showing any errors but still it's not re-ordering the users?

Comment: It's giving an error `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`. But if I re-order the order_by() condition to `order_by('receiver', '-created_at'')`  as error requires, It will no longer re-order them ?

Comment: I wanted you to try that. I guess it will work. updated the answer also

Comment: No, it's not re-ordering the users. It's simply ignoring the `created_at` (as it's coming after) and using `receiver` instead