# Django: Distinct and Order_by Together

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to build a messaging app. Here's my model,

```
class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sender")
    receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="receiver")
    msg_content = models.TextField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is what I tried in view,

```
data = User.objects.filter(Q(sender__receiver=request.user) | Q(receiver__sender=request.user)).order_by('-receiver')
```

Here `User` is the built in user model of django

In the template,

```
{% for abc in data %}
    {{ abc}} <br/>
{% endfor %}
```

Here i wants to filter the distinct users and re-order them based upon the fact that to whom `request.user` sent new message recently (as we see on social media platforms).

I tried almost everything with

```
data = Message.objects.filter(Q(sender=request.user) | Q(receiver=request.user))....(order, values, distinct)
```

But either it's not re-ordering or it's not working with distinct() when used together.

How can I do that with User model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django order\_by() filter with distinct()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582966/django-order-by-filter-with-distinct)

Comment: Also, I think you should read the documentation about the `distinct` (especially the `Note` about using `distinct` and `order_by` together) https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#distinct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: Distinct Users Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47279487/django-distinct-users-filtering)